# Is last_activity_date updated on answer deletion?

Tags: discussion, questions, last-activity

Is the value of the last_activity_date property of a question object updated when an answer for the question is deleted?

For example, when there are 2 answers for a question (no edits to the question) and when the newer answer of the 2 is deleted, will the post timestamp of the other answer overwrite the last_activity_date  of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The last activity date will still be set to the timestamp of the deleted answer.

This makes sense if you consider that answers are only soft-deleted and some users (those with enough reputation on the site + moderators) can still see them when they view the question, though it is potentially confusing for everyone else.